# Why can't I change this picture in tampermonkey?

Tags: image, tampermonkey

So this is really frustrating... on the mymaths website: https://www.mymaths.co.uk/, there's an image of a primary school child on a computer with this image address: https://www.mymaths.co.uk/assets/images/big/primary-school-photo-2.jpg.
I've tried so many things, but I can't seem to replace it.

Say I wanted to replace it with a picture of a hamburger, with this address: https://images.ctfassets.net/sd2voc54sjgs/5L6livQvCw28S04IUSAcm6/6482ea1819e86be1b4f7e85bfbbfe9a6/Blog_Header_Hamburger_History_Option.png?fm=jpg&q=80&fl=progressive&w=1100.

So far I've tried lots of threads, but this image seems to be different from images on other websites, which is why my code isn't working on it:

```
var images3 = document.getElementsByTagName ("img");
var i3=0;
while(i3<images3.length)
{
if(images[i3].src == "https://www.mymaths.co.uk/assets/images/big/primary-school-photo-2.jpg")
{
images[i3].src = "https://images.ctfassets.net/sd2voc54sjgs/5L6livQvCw28S04IUSAcm6/6482ea1819e86be1b4f7e85bfbbfe9a6/Blog_Header_Hamburger_History_Option.png?fm=jpg&q=80&fl=progressive&w=1100";
}
i3=i3+1;
}
```

Can somebody help me please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was new for me too. Apparently, [the `<picture>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) is not just a wrapper - it's a smarter version of `<img>`.

It allows to chose different URLs for the image tag depending on screen size and type. For example, try to do this in developper tools:

[image]

I replaced `srcset` for the `<source>` that has `(max-width: 767px)`, which means it is active when browser window is smaller than `767px`. Now if you resize browser window to make it smaller, at some point the original image will be raplaced with burger image.

So what you want to do is to replace all `<source>`'s srcset. This worked for me:

```
// Limit the list of omages on those that are under `<picture>` tag
const images = document.querySelectorAll("picture img, picture source");
// RegExp to check if we want to replace the URL
const replaceChecker = /primary-school-photo-2\.jpg$/i;
// The replacement URL
const replaceWith = "https://images.ctfassets.net/sd2voc54sjgs/5L6livQvCw28S04IUSAcm6/6482ea1819e86be1b4f7e85bfbbfe9a6/Blog_Header_Hamburger_History_Option.png?fm=jpg&q=80&fl=progressive&w=1100";

for(const image of images) {
  // Pick the name of the attribute we want to change based on whether it's <img> or <source>
  const srcAttributeName = image.tagName.toLowerCase() == "img" ? "src" : "srcset";
  const oldURL = image[srcAttributeName] + "";
  if(replaceChecker.test(oldURL)) {
    image[srcAttributeName] = replaceWith;
  }
}
```

You could improve that by checking the `media` attribute and if it says minimum screen width, use URL for smaller image of the hamburger. That is set by the `w` GET param in the hamburger image's URL.